# Get HTTP POST Response in Rails Controler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post

I have two rails apps. App #1 sends a post request from a controller action to another controller action in App #2. I want to be able to read in App #1 the response to that POST.

App #1 Controller:

```
  require 'net/http'
  # get the url that we need to post to
  url = URI.parse('http://app2.com/sessions/login_request')
  # build the params string
  post_args1 = { 
    'username' => 'my@test.com' 
  }
  # send the request
  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, post_args1)

  #HOW do I read :token and :tokenMnemonic here??
```

App #2 controller:

```
def login_request
  # do some logic here
  render :json => {
    :result => "OK",
    :token => random_token,
    :tokenMnemonic => tokenMnemonic
  }
end
```

The question is how can I read :token and :tokenMnemonic from the POST response received at the controller of App #1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `resp` represents the response object. You can use the [`#body`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html#method-i-body) method to get the body of the response as String.

If the body is a String serialization of a JSON, simply parse it back to fetch the elements.

```
hash = JSON.parse(resp.body)
hash['token']
# => ...
```

Comment: Yeah! It works! I take it's a synchronous POST, right?

Comment: Simone, I'm sorry for contacting you like this, but I didn't know how else to get in touch with you. I noticed you voted to put my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743387/how-to-increment-upvote-total-in-my-view-after-successful-ajax-request-to-upvote on hold. It's been edited to be more clear now, and I badly need an answer soon. Please consider withdrawing your vote, so I can place a bounty on it as soon as possible.